# How to convert a one line string into a formatted XML string?

Tags: java, xml

I'm recieving unformatted XML strings, which must be formatted for some tasks.

Let's say I have the following input:

```
<phoneDetails><name>My Phone X</name><displaySize>920x480px</displaySize></phoneDetails>
```

My expected output would be:

```
<phoneDetails>
    <name>My Phone X</name>
    <displaySize>920x480px</displaySize>
</phoneDetails>
```

I have already tried to serialize the unformatted string in an object using JacksonXml and then deserializing it back to a formatted string.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Anyway, this didn't solve my problem, since the XML element names can be different. For example the XML element `name` could also have the name `name-for-other-purpose`. This way it would be very painful.

Does anybody know how I could solve that problem? Maybe using REGEX or something else?

I highly appreciate any kind of help, cheers!

---

First try of importing the XML string as regular object.

I created this class, which holds the inline XML string.

```
public class InlineString {

    public String content;

    public InlineString (String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

}
```

After that I tried to pretty print it.

```
InlineString obj = new InlineString("<phoneDetails><name>My Phone X</name><displaySize>920x480px</displaySize></phoneDetails>");

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new XmlMapper();
objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
String xml = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(command);
```

But the output is not the same as expected, probably because of the regular object.

```
<InlineString>
  <content>&lt;phoneDetails>&lt;name>My Phone X&lt;/name>&lt;displaySize>920x480px&lt;/displaySize>&lt;/phoneDetails></content>
</InlineString>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a `TransformerFactory` using `TransformerFactory.newInstance()`.
2. Create an identity transformer using `factory.newTransformer()`.
3. Set the output properties on the transformer using `transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes")`
4. Create a source: `new StreamSource(new StringReader(inputXmlString))`
5. Create a result: `new StreamResult(new StringWriter())`
6. Do the transformation using `transformer.transform(source, result)`

Answer (score -1):

The JacksonXML [pretty](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/dataformats/jacksonxml-dataformat.html) option should give you the formatting you're looking for, but you will also need to edit the object before serializing it again.

Comment: As I said, it would be very painful for me to use JacksonXML, since the structure of the XML string may be completly different, which makes is hard to serialize in an object. Or do I miss something?

Comment: I think you're missing something. ;) You can use JacksonXML to import the XML into a regular object, edit it as you like, then export it again back to XML, formatted as you wish.

Comment: I've added my first try of importing the XML string as regular object, but I think I still missing something. May it possible to give me an example on how I could use the pretty option?

Comment: There is a good tutorial here for pulling the XML into a java object, then exporting it again as XML: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-xml-serialization-and-deserialization

Comment: I don't see any way to format the XML string with JacksonXML **without specifying a class with properties for all the XML elements.**

Comment: Ok, taking a step backwards, what is it that you are looking to achieve in context?